# To atone or to cover ?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, yom-kippur, commentaries

The root for the word Kippur as in Yom Kippur is כפר but what does it mean linguistically or commentarial?

It's explained that the root mean 'to cover' or 'to atone'?

Where does this difference come from?: Is it a difference in the way each is derived, like one from a verb and one from a noun? or a difference in stems (Qal, Piel etc)?

So 1) what does כפר mean and 
2) how is the difference in meaning (cover/atone) explained

Comment: Who says it means to cover?

Comment: @user613 מעל הכפרת

Comment: @user613 מבית ומחוץ בכופר

Comment: I wrote about this in a sermon I gave many years ago. I have to dig it out. Essentially, atonement is a way of "covering up" the sins. I.e., when G-d forgives the person who repents, it is as if the sin didn't exist. I think Talmud in Yoma explains how this works in a bit more detail. But, there is definitely a connection in the same root word being used to mean both concepts. Note, by the way that the same root can also mean "to deny". Same idea - denial "covers up" the truth or existence of the facts.